# PHP: HTML markup problem while displaying trimmed HTML markups

Tags: php, html, markup

I am using a Richtext box control to post some data in one page.
and I am saving the data to my db table with the HTML mark up Ex : This is <b >my bold </b > text

I am displaying the first 50 characters of this column in another page. Now When i am saving, if i save a Sentence (with more than 50 chars )with bold tag applied and in my other page when i trim this (for taking first 50 chars) I would lost the closing b tag (</b>) .So  the bold is getting applied to rest of my contents in that page.

How can i solve this ? How can i check which all open tags are not closed ? is there anyeasy way to do this in PHP. Is there any function to remove my entire HTML tags / mark up and give me the sentence as plain text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/strip_tags

the strip_tags function will remove any tags you might have.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
$textWithoutTags = strip_tags($html);
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally use [HTML::Truncate](http://search.cpan.org/~ashley/HTML-Truncate-0.16/lib/HTML/Truncate.pm) for this. Of course, being a Perl module, you won't be able to use it directly in your PHP - but the source code does show a working approach (which is to use an HTML parser).

An alternative approach, might be to truncate as you are doing at the moment, and then try to fix it using [Tidy](http://uk.php.net/tidy).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the HTML tags to remain, but be closed properly, see [PHP: Truncate HTML, ignoring tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/1193598). Otherwise, read on:

[strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) will remove HTML tags, but not HTML entities (such as `&amp;`), which could still cause problems if truncated.

To handle entities as well, one can use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) to decode entities after stripping tags, then trim, and finally reencode the entities with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
$text = "1 &lt; 2\n";
print $text;
print htmlspecialchars(substr(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($text), ENT_QUOTES), 0, 3));
```

(Note use of ENT_QUOTES to actually convert *all* entities.)

Result:

```
1 < 2
1 <
```

<sub>**Footnote:** The above only works for entities that can be decoded to ISO-8859-1. If you need support for international characters, you should already be working with UTF-8 encoded strings, and simply need to specify that in the call to [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).</sub>