# Cut out HTML tags from Smarty variable

Tags: smarty, truncate

I was building a Smarty template. All was fine before i checked the validation.

The Truncate of the Description is included but the end tag will not be added. Any tag addings will not help.

The truncate is called like

```
{$products_data.PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION|truncate:300}
```

The Description has more than 300 characters and it starts and ends with `p` tags. After the truncate has cut it then i have just the starting tag `<p>`.

Is there a way to cut HTML tags out for truncate?

Comment: An alternative approach is to close all opened tags, see [Truncate a HTML formatted text with SMARTY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671053/truncate-a-html-formatted-text-with-smarty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather difficult to filter out html tags, truncate the text, and then place back the html tags. I would suggest that you drop all html tags with strip_tags and then truncate the resulting text. If you want, you can then embed what's left into <p> tags:

> {$products_data.PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION|strip_tags|truncate:300}

Comment: Yeah definitely need to strip tags (all of them), you don't want something like `<p>Check out this product: <img src="` Just wrap that line in `<p>` tags if necessary. Plus stuff like images or links will "incorrectly" increase the "real" character count (of the actual words) for truncate, you could very well end up with an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

i ran into the same problem during a project and found a great smarty modifier called "html_substr" written by Benjamin Lupu/Edward Dale. Simply add a new php file called "modifier.html_substr.php" into the smarty/libs/plugins directory:

(Sorry - i don' remember the source so I'm just posting the whole function here):

```
<?php
/*
* Smarty plugin
*
-------------------------------------------------------------
* File: modifier.html_substr.php
* Type: modifier
* Name: html_substr
* Version: 1.0
* Date: June 19th, 2003
* Purpose: Cut a string preserving any tag nesting and matching.
* Install: Drop into the plugin directory.
* Author: Original Javascript Code: Benjamin Lupu <hide@address.com>
* Translation to PHP & Smarty: Edward Dale <hide@address.com>
* Modification to add a string: Sebastian Kuhlmann <hide@address.com>
* Modification to put the added string before closing <p> or <li> tags by Peter Carter http://www.podhawk.com
-------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function smarty_modifier_html_substr($string, $length, $addstring="")
{

//some nice italics for the add-string
 if (!empty($addstring)) $addstring = "<i> " . $addstring . "</i>";

if (strlen($string) > $length) {
    if( !empty( $string ) && $length>0 ) {
        $isText = true;
        $ret = "";
        $i = 0;

        $currentChar = "";
        $lastSpacePosition = -1;
        $lastChar = "";

        $tagsArray = array();
        $currentTag = "";
        $tagLevel = 0;

        $addstringAdded = false;

        $noTagLength = strlen( strip_tags( $string ) );

        // Parser loop
        for( $j=0; $j<strlen( $string ); $j++ ) {

            $currentChar = substr( $string, $j, 1 );
            $ret .= $currentChar;

            // Lesser than event
            if( $currentChar == "<") $isText = false;

                // Character handler
                if( $isText ) {

                    // Memorize last space position
                    if( $currentChar == " " ) { $lastSpacePosition = $j; }
                    else { $lastChar = $currentChar; }

                    $i++;
                    } else {
                    $currentTag .= $currentChar;
                    }

                    // Greater than event
                    if( $currentChar == ">" ) {
                        $isText = true;

                        // Opening tag handler
                        if( ( strpos( $currentTag, "<" ) !== FALSE ) &&
                        ( strpos( $currentTag, "/>" ) === FALSE ) &&
                        ( strpos( $currentTag, "</") === FALSE ) ) {

                        // Tag has attribute(s)
                        if( strpos( $currentTag, " " ) !== FALSE ) {
                            $currentTag = substr( $currentTag, 1, strpos( $currentTag, " " ) - 1 );
                            } else {
                            // Tag doesn't have attribute(s)
                            $currentTag = substr( $currentTag, 1, -1 );
                            }

                            array_push( $tagsArray, $currentTag );

                            } else if( strpos( $currentTag, "</" ) !== FALSE ) {
                            array_pop( $tagsArray );
                            }

                        $currentTag = "";
                        }

                    if( $i >= $length) {
                    break;
                    }
                }

        // Cut HTML string at last space position
        if( $length < $noTagLength ) {
            if( $lastSpacePosition != -1 ) {
            $ret = substr( $string, 0, $lastSpacePosition );
            } else {
            $ret = substr( $string, $j );
            }
        }

        // Close broken XHTML elements
            while( sizeof( $tagsArray ) != 0 ) {
            $aTag = array_pop( $tagsArray );
                // if a <p> or <li> tag needs to be closed, put the add-string in first
                if (($aTag == "p" || $aTag == "li") && strlen($string) > $length) {
                $ret .= $addstring;
                $addstringAdded = true;
                }
            $ret .= "</" . $aTag . ">\n";
            }

        } else {
        $ret = "";
        }

    // if we have not added the add-string already 
    if ( strlen($string) > $length && $addstringAdded == false) {
        return( $ret.$addstring );
        }
        else {
        return ( $ret );
        }
    }
    else {
    return ( $string );
    }
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
{$products_data.PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION|html_substr:300:' ...'}
```

Comment: Did you try to use strip_tags?

Comment: Hi, no because strip_tags does not fit my needs. Stripping all tags and losing formatting is not the solution but a workaround. So i came up with this solution.

Comment: simplyray, source is [here](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=533). There are more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a solution to truncate the text without impacting the html tags.
I wanted to truncate the text of the short description to 300 characters and keep my html.

So I replaced

> {$product.description nofilter}

By

> {Tools::truncateString($product.description, 300) nofilter}

The solution works very well on prestashop 1.7