# How to truncate an html text and still maintain the format, in PHP

Tags: php, format, truncate

I have text with minimal tags like 'a','b','i' etc inside it.
Now i want to truncate the text to 100 chars and still want to maintian the formatting. 
I don;t want to strip the tags off from the text.

Is it possible? how can it be done.

Comment: A simple sample of what you have and what you'd like to see would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP substr() and strip_tags() while retaining formatting and without breaking HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398725/using-php-substr-and-strip-tags-while-retaining-formatting-and-without-breaki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this answered in another question here,  The link provided was http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7125
by Dennis Pedrie on [How to truncate HTML to certain number of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974833/how-to-truncate-html-to-certain-number-of-characters/2975162#2975162)

Hope this helps, its basically a short class that will do what you want with a very simple call, if you scroll down some people have made a few improvements too.

Regards
Luke

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to do it using javascript, but a solution using php is possible if you got the tags + contents ont the server side. All you need to do is to parse your tag+content so that you separate the tags from the content and then truncate your content text to 100 characters. Ad the separated tags you still have in a varable and there you go.

Very simple example:

```
$fulltag_as_string = '<b>This is my text ... blah, blah .. with length more than 100 characters</b>';

$arr = split(">",$fulltag_as_string);
$arr2 = split("<",$fulltag_as_string);
$arr3 = split("<",$arr[1]);

$truncated_text = strlen($arr3[0] > 100) ? substr($arr3[0],0,100) : $arr3[0];

echo $resulting_tag = $arr[0].">".$truncated_text."<".$arr2[2];
```