# How do i truncate a post (HTML/Markdown) but not give invalid markup

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine

is there a way i can truncate a post. eg. create a blog summary. while not breaking the markup?

- 1st i am thinking of HTML
- if that can be done, how do i work on markdown posts

i use PHP/Zend Framework/MySQL/Doctrine2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of HTML [it's been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/php-truncate-html-ignoring-tags/1193661#1193661).

In case of Markdown, you could convert whole Markdown text to HTML, and see previous point. Otherwise you'd have to write Markdown parser (state machine) that parses source up to a certain point, keeping track of all open constructs, and then closes all of them.