# Looking for PHP function to close HTML tags

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for a PHP function to close HTML tags.

I'm building a site that has admins entering content in a "WYSIWYG" editor. Some of the screens will only show part of the content and then prompt the user to "click for more". So I need to be able to close all the HTML tags that were opened in the part of the content that is initially displayed.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder how Wordpress does this? They seem to have a solution for it

Comment: and how would such a function close these tags as it was intended by the user? `<b>hello<u>stack<i>overflow` should it be `<b>hello</b><u>stack</u><i>overflow</i>` or `<b>hello<u>stack<i>overflow</i></u></b>` there's no reliable way of handling this.

Comment: @stillstanding: The last result has the **same effect**. It would be obvious that it's then the last one. Otherwise the WYSIWYG user would certainly put some end tags in to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: same effect as what? the WYSIWYG editor's output or the user's desired output?

Comment: @stillstanding: How could anyone but the person that wrote that mess know what was intended?

Comment: @jason: exactly why i said "there's no reliable way of handling this"

Comment: It's irrelevant to the OP. Regard the entire fragment as initially valid, looks fine etc. Now truncate it at an arbitrary position. Now figure out how to close dangling tags.

If you truncated <b>hello<u>stack<i>overflow then the only logical course of action is to close with </i></u></b>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can do this by running the HTML through something like [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). An extension for this is [available in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php).

For example, suppose you had a fragment like this

```
<h1>hello

<table>
<tr><td>and you cut the text right here... </t
```

Thorny! Dangling tags and a truncation in mid-tag!

Here's what you'd get back

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hello</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>and you cut the text right here...</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Pretty impressive! Now all you need to do is just extract the repaired fragment back out of the body element.

See also the answers to [PHP: Truncate HTML, ignoring tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/php-truncate-html-ignoring-tags)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with PHP's native [DOM library](http://www.php.net/dom). Creating a `DOMDocument` object with the truncated contents, then converting it back to a string will result in a normalized DOM tree not unlike what a browser would produce with a `DocumentFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have the "click for more" not extend beyond any tags that need to be closed. For instance:

```
<body>
  <div id="main_content">
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="post"></div>
      <div id="initially_displayed">
        <p>Your post goes here</p>
        <a onclick="display displayed_later">Click for more</a>
        <div id="displayed_later" style="display:none;">
          <p>More goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice how `displayed_later` is inside of `initially_displayed`. This way even if `displayed_later` is not displayed, `initially_displayed` can still close appropriately.

You would then just use JavaScript to set the style on `displayed_later` to `display:block;`