# Truncated string with special character because of length

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I need to limit the length of a string. I do it like this:

```
$str.='<div class="timt">'.substr($row['summary'],0,180).'</div>';
```

The problem is that in my language, there are some special chars like áéíúó , when the string "ends" in a special character, the end of the line echo `h&eac` instead of `hé`.
I think that's because of `&eacute` or something like that... but how can i solve this so this is not "truncated"?

I found some suggestions but none is working [How to truncate HTML with special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834329/how-to-truncate-html-with-special-characters).. is there any chance some one can point how can i solve this.

I also tried this but it's not working.

```
$str.='<div class="timt">'.mb_strcut($row['summary'],0,180,"UTF-8").'</div>';
```

After the answer of André i try this

```
$description = html_entity_decode($row['summary']);
$str.='<div class="timedesctt" onclick="location.href=\''.$this->make_url("item/view/".$row['itemid'],array('city_name'=>$this->get_english_city_name($row['city']))).'\';">'.mb_strcut($description,0,180,"UTF-8").'</div>';
```

Which now just have issue.. it's showing `?` instead of `á`

I have my database encoded as utf8 unicode ci and the charset is set as utf8

Solution : `html_entity_decode($strint,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to truncate HTML with special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834329/how-to-truncate-html-with-special-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to convert your html entites with [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).
Then use [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/mb_substr), and convert them back.

I can provide with an example if necessary but check [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).

Comment: thats all i need to know, thanks if i had problems i will update, thanks

Comment: even when i have set up "UTF" in the mb_substr() i get the ? symbol instead of the letter á, or é , why is that????