# how to truncate a string with TAGS correctly?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Truncate HTML, ignoring tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/php-truncate-html-ignoring-tags)

i have to truncate a string after n characters but I can't truncate the words, I mean:

`'This is a text'` if i want to truncate after 6 characters i can't get `'this i'` BUT `'this'`

I have solved this problem using `str_word_count()` but now i need to do the same thing without count the tags length and without truncate them.

Example:

`'The <b>text</b>'` and i want to truncate after 5 characters i need to get all the text (
`'The <b>text</b>'`) because the 5th character is inside the tags and i can't truncate tags.

How can i do it?