# How to shorten HTML text in Php

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Truncate HTML, ignoring tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/php-truncate-html-ignoring-tags)

I have html data saved in db. I want to display html as shortened..
I try to use `mb_strstr` function like this;

```
$str = mb_strstr($this->htmlData, "</p>",true);
echo $str."</p>";
```

It echos the first paragraph of the html. But the problem is html is filled in admin panel and sometimes first paragraph is not have enough text. 
I also dont want to use fixed character position with `substr` because sometimes let say 200 character can be a html tag so it produces invalid format html formatted output.

So I want to learn best practice for this kind of problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You've got yourself some fun ahead of you here. Lesson to learn is don't store html in the db. Your mb_strstr with that close p tag should prevent it from splitting in a tag, but it doesn't mean you didn't split in a place that leaves another tag wide open.

Comment: What do you mean dont store it in the db? It's kinda cms like wordpress.. User input blog posts in WYSIWYG editor then save html source in db.. what is the problem exactly here?

Comment: i'm just being a doofus. you could store a summary that uses strip_tags() to remove html, but that may be unreliable in other ways. Probably less of a pain than trying to regex the string and close all tags on read though.

Answer (score 1):

Add some custom tag or code into your WYSIWYG editor (example: `<separator>` or `...`). You could use it to separate introduction part from the rest of the article. That will help you avoid mess with PHP tags being unclosed in introduction part. Also it gives author option to decide manually which part of text would be good for introduction.

Another wise think that can be done would be to make a separate field in the database for introduction part. Yes, it would cost more memory but it would give an option to author to write juicy introduction text to have more people open full article...

Comment: Actually I like the idea of having custom tag. But it's inefficient for admin users, editing html with new tags. Maybe implementing a new custom button on WYSIWYG to do it automatically for user.. Anyway it's also another effort, I don't want to lose focus with implementing on editor.. New column is kinda not user friendly looks like.

Comment: unless you do it automatically, transparent to the user. They don't need to be aware of the new field. Are you using a packaged CMS or your own?

Comment: I'm using my own implementation with CKEditor @KaiQing

Comment: I found this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/php-truncate-html-ignoring-tags what do you think about performance guys?

Comment: I think the performance would be a non issue if you truncate on update (add / edit) and save the results in its own field. Since you're using your own thing you have full control.

Comment: cool i thought it'll run every time i print :)