# Truncate HTML content to specified character/word count, while preserving tags

Tags: php, html

I recently had the need to truncate post content that contains HTML (for a post excerpt/summary, etc.). This is usually done by manually entering an excerpt for the post, but for this specific project, I need to do it automatically.

I tried to create a simple method which just takes a character count and sub-strings the content. However, this does not work all the time as it may truncate the content within an HTML tag/attribute.

eg:

```
<?php
function truncateText($string, $chars) { return substr($string, 0, $chars); }

$content = "<div><p>some content</p><a href='http://google.com'>Let's go to google</a></div>";    

echo truncateText($content,40); //returns "<div><p>some content</p><a href='http:/"
```

as you can see, it will return a broken HTML, which will not render properly. How would I be able to truncate content, yet retain HTML tags?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/php-truncate-html-ignoring-tags

Comment: @Akam yup, modifying that function did it for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach yelds many problems. Do you want to truncate at the 40 characters, then add as many tags as needed until they are closed? Or do you prefer to truncate at 40 and trim as much as needed to make the tags work? Do the tags add up to the 40 characters or they are ignored when counting? There are many problems with this as you can see. However, there's an alternative commonly found for summaries:

**Delete the tags and truncate the text**. The summary is normally just a small extract of text, a paragraph, with simple format. You don't want lists here and in most cases and stripping a link or two is okay for this.

However, if you really want to go down that road, I'd recommend meaningfully reading the html tags with some [DOM parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/938236), but to know how to do that you will first need to answer the first questions I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care if formatting is removed from your text, then just send the string through the PHP function `strip-tags()` before you do anything else.  [Instructions here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this won't work as the HTML needs to be kept.