# Am I misunderstanding strlen()?

Tags: php, strlen

I'm trying to properly understand `strlen()` in PHP to make a application where text is shortened and finished with a `...`

My code:

```
  $prize_text = "Learn how to eat pizza TODAY";
          if (strlen($prize_text) > 24) {
        $prize_text = substr($prize_text, 0, 21) . '...';
        }
```

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

```
$prize_text = "Watch Good Day Sunshine Today!";
```

[image: #2 Visual Aid]

```
$prize_text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

[image: #3 Visual Aid]

**Why is everything not matching up? I want one uniform standard of shortening the text and then appending three dots. What is wrong with my code?**

Comment: What is wrong? You cut the string and keep the 21th first characters? Not sure to understand your problem, what do you expect from your 3 examples?

Comment: You are probably using a font that does not have fixed character width, so you will get varying line lengths.

Comment: @Rasclatt I'm not following you. Would you please elaborate? I'm using Open Sans and 18px font size...

Comment: Look at the difference in widths between the 'h' and the 'i' in your font. Some characters take up much less space than others.

Comment: @olibiaz I want each example to stop at the same place, right before the end of the div. Not too much before or after...

Comment: Ok so your problem is css or font used more than php. The php part works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/truncate-text-containing-html-ignoring-tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong tool for the job. You want CSS instead to avoid the breaking problem you're having.

```
#element {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**Advantages**

- You can hide/show the text at will, whereas with PHP the text sent is already rendered in the document.
- Will work for multiple situations whereas the PHP is hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` count the number of characters in string not space occupied by the string on viewport. You can make same length by make all characters in samecase- either in lowercase or uppercase, to make all string with same width you may take reference of http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html