# HTML tag <em> appearing on live website only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a website using php with javascript and jquery. Everything seems to be normal when I see the output locally, but when I upload it live, some parts of the website gets affected by the  tag. I did not even try to add this tag before.

My bootstrap grid does not stay on one row anymore and some of my paragraph tags and headers turn italic all of a sudden. What or where is the origin of this  tag?

Example:
[image: 1]

This is my php for each to output the contents of my database. It echos a picture, a header tag, a paragraph tag and a "Read More" link. 
Locally they are all the same, but in the live website as you can see, the second output has its "Read More" in italic only but the third one has it on every text.

```
<?php
  foreach($lstBlog as $rowBlog) {
    $datetime = new DateTime($rowBlog['createddate']);
  echo'<div class="col-md-4 col-md-4">';
  echo'<div class="mb-2">';
  echo'<img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/_uploads/blog/'.$rowBlog['featured_photo_thumb'].'">';
  echo'<div class="card-body">';
  echo'<p class="color-lighter-grey date-font">'.$datetime->format('F j, Y').'</p>';
  echo'<h4 class="dk_lemon color-light-grey">'.$rowBlog['blog_name'].'</h4>';
  echo'<p class="color-lighter-grey">';
  echo substr($rowBlog['blog_description'], 0, 100);
  echo strlen($rowBlog['blog_description']) > 100 ? ".....</p>" : "</p>";
  echo'<a href="blog.php?i='.$rowBlog['blogid'].'">';
  echo'<h4 class="dk_lemon read-more">Read More</h4></a></div></div></div>';
} ?>
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing the rendered HTML. Maybe the HTML gets mangled when the description is truncated; for example, a `</em>` or some other closing tag gets stripped off. What is the value of `$rowBlog['blog_description']`? Are any HTML tags included in the string?

Comment: Do you include any third party libraries into the page? If so remove them see if problem persists. If so its one of those libraries. Otherwise you are going to need to provide something more like a live example or at least a [mcve]

Comment: the weird thing is that i never added an <em> tag

Comment: See [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) or, if the tags are important, the more complicated solutions in [Truncate text containing HTML, ignoring tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/truncate-text-containing-html-ignoring-tags).

Comment: You only need one `echo`. You can concatenate... or use one of the other string building options. This won't fix the italic issue, just a note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your issue might be coming from discrepancies between what you have in your local environment and what you have in the production environment. At a glance, just looking at the screenshot, I'm guessing that something in the second column opens the `<em>` tag and then doesn't close it.

[image]

This makes me think that this might be an issue with how you generate that excerpt in that section, are you stripping all the HTML? Just from the screenshot, I can see a situation where it's getting 'trimmed' and closing, not including the enclosing `<em>` tag.

If my theory is correct, what you'd have to do is ensure that the output that is generated for the excerpt doesn't include any HTML (stripped).

As mentioned in one of the comments by [shadowdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924299/showdev) to your original question, the relevant function that you're looking for is [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

A more in-depth explanation to accomplish what you're trying to do can be found in another question:

[Truncate text containing HTML, ignoring tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193500/truncate-text-containing-html-ignoring-tags)

Comment: thanks for the solution, i used a substring because the output uses tags in the database. the <em> tag did not close because i limited the characters up to the point where the last words were in italic.